# How to modify "for" loop in existing program

Tags: perl

I want to modify this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Call of CPAN
use warnings;
use strict;

use Cwd;

# Variables
my $i         = 0;
my $directory = getcwd;
my $file      = "options";

# Opening output file and adding the header on first row
open( FILE, ">>OLTP.txt" ) or die( "Could not create file OLTP.txt" );
print FILE "User script,Serveur Name,Instance Name,Date of script,Serveur Name2,Instance Name2,ADVANCED_COMPRESSION~HEADER,TABLE_COMPRESSION~HEADER,2,count,DATA_DICTIONARY_VIEW,TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,PARTITION_NAME,COMPRESSION,COMPRESS_FOR,\n";
close FILE;

# Loop while files are found
foreach my $files ( list_files( $directory, 1, $file ) ) {

    print "File : $files\n";
    singlefile( $files, $file );
}

# Recursion and list integration
sub list_files {
    my ( $directory, $recurse, $file ) = @_;

    require File::Spec;

    # Search in subdirectory or not
    if ( ( not defined $recurse ) || ( $recurse != 1 ) ) {
        $recurse = 0;
    }

    # verification directory
    if ( not defined $directory ) {
        die "No named directory\n";
    }

    # Opening a directory
    opendir my $fh_rep, $directory or die "Can not open directory $directory\n";

    # List files and directories, except (. and ..)
    my @fic_rep = grep { !/^\.\.?$/ } readdir $fh_rep;

    # Closing directory
    closedir $fh_rep or die "Unable to close directory $directory\n";

    # Fill list with found files
    my @files;

    # File or folder? if file: add files to the table. if record: start the recursion
    foreach my $nom ( @fic_rep ) {

        my $mycurrentfile = File::Spec->catdir( $directory, $nom );

        if (    -f $mycurrentfile
            and $mycurrentfile =~ m/$file/
            and $mycurrentfile =~ m/\.csv$/i ) {

            push( @files, $mycurrentfile );
        }
        elsif ( -d $mycurrentfile and $recurse == 1 ) {

            push( @files, list_files( $mycurrentfile, $recurse, $file ) );    # recursion
        }
    }

    return @files;
}

## Merge data after filtering
sub singlefile {
    my ( $file, $out ) = @_;

    # Open file
    open( FILE, $file ) or die( "error occured while opening file" );

    # Create list from file
    my @save = <FILE>;

    close( FILE );

    # Empty table rows which do not meet criteria
    foreach ( @save ) {

        $_ = "" unless ( $_ =~ m/"ENABLED","OLTP",/ && $_ =~ m/^GREP/ );
        $_ = "" if ( $_ =~ m/SYSMAN/ || m/SYS/ );

        chomp $_;

    }

    # Open output file, add data, close
    open( FILE, ">>OLTP.txt" ) or die( "error occured while opening file OLTP.txt" );

    foreach ( @save ) {

        print FILE $_ . "\n" if ( $_ );
    }

    close( FILE );
}
```

It seems to do the following

1. Create txt with header
2. Create list of files based on every files that match with criteria (option, csv)
3. For each file in the list, fill with all rows and then remove what do not match with the criteria `unless` and `if`
4. Push everything into the file with header (oltp.txt)

My Goal :

1. Create txt with header
2. Create list of file based on every files that match with criteria (option, csv)
3. For each files of the list, ***fill only with the First rows that match with the criteria `unless` and `if`***
4. Push everything into the file with header `oltp.txt`. The final result should be the text with header and then a maximum of one line per file if the criteria match.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. It seems you have forgotten to ask a question. Please [edit] your post and include an actual question, sample input and expected output. See [mvce] for more information about that. Also, did you write the code, or are you maintaining it?

Comment: You may wish to use the `File::Find` library, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel.... http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html

Comment: Why does `singlefile` take 2 parameters but never uses the 2nd one?